# Mapbox android sdk Query for features

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox-android

so i have an app that renders like 20 ~ 100 k of features in a map, and i want to query from them and for example look for a "id" with number 222222 and add or edit a property in that feature in real time.

I can do that by re render all the layout, but i want to update point by point. It should be easy

if you guys can help me

Here is the funcion to draw it:

```
  var latS: Double = 0.0
        var lngS: Double = 0.0
        var listFeatures: MutableList<Feature> = mutableListOf()
        for (module in list) {
            val f = Feature.fromGeometry(Point.fromLngLat(module.longitude, module.latitude))
            f.addNumberProperty("id", module.id)
            f.addStringProperty(SmartConstants.LAYOUT.SELECTED, "no")
            listFeatures.add(f)
        }
        plantModules = listFeatures
        val features = FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(listFeatures)


        mapView.getMapboxMap().loadStyle(
            style(styleUri = currentStyle) {
                +geoJsonSource("source") {
                    featureCollection(features)
                    cluster(true)
                    clusterMaxZoom(14)
                }
                +circleLayer("circleLayer", "source") {
                    circleRadius(12.0)
                    circleColor(
                        match {
                            get("defect")
                            stop {
                                literal("MINOR")
                                rgb(3.0, 255.0, 20.0)
                            }
                            stop {
                                literal("MEDIUM")
                                rgb(255.0, 255.0, 34.0)
                            }
                            stop {
                                literal("MAJOR")
                                rgb(255.0, 16.0, 16.0)
                            }
                            stop {
                                literal("OTHER")
                                rgb(174.0, 9.0, 255.0)
                            }
                            rgb(255.0, 255.0, 255.0)
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        )

        addOnClickEventPlant()
```

And the funcion to re render them:

```
private fun drawDefects(list: List<Module>) {

        plantModules.get(10).addStringProperty("defect", "MAJOR")

        val features = FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(plantModules)


        mapView.getMapboxMap().loadStyle(
            style(styleUri = currentStyle) {
                +geoJsonSource("source") {
                    featureCollection(features)
                    cluster(true)
                    clusterMaxZoom(14)
                }
                +circleLayer("circleLayer", "source") {
                    circleRadius(12.0)
                    circleColor(
                        match {
                            get("defect")
                            stop {
                                literal("MINOR")
                                rgb(3.0, 255.0, 20.0)
                            }
                            stop {
                                literal("MEDIUM")
                                rgb(255.0, 255.0, 34.0)
                            }
                            stop {
                                literal("MAJOR")
                                rgb(255.0, 16.0, 16.0)
                            }
                            stop {
                                literal("OTHER")
                                rgb(174.0, 9.0, 255.0)
                            }
                            rgb(255.0, 255.0, 255.0)
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        )

        addOnClickEventPlant()

    }
```